# trying to use selenium for firefox and running into errors

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I get the following error:

```
File "C:\Users\ryanv\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\service.py", line 44, in __init__
    log_file = open(log_path, "a+") if log_path is not None and log_path != "" else None
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'geckodriver.log'
```

when I'm trying to run

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
```

Could this be because firefox is in the pythonfoundation folder and I have another folder where python is?

I have tried adding geckodriver to path as well as downloading it and putting it into my other python folder however nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

in your cmd line type: where python

and put the gecko file in that folder where python is located